# Issue importing font via CSS

Tags: html, css, font-face

I am currently trying to import a font with the @font-face CSS element, but it is not working/ showing up. It is the font Francaise from Dafont.com, it is in the css folder with the stylesheet, but will not change my header font to desired font.

I have already tried searching Stack for similar queries, but each attempt is in vain.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Francaise';
    src: local('Francaise Regular Demo.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

I have anticipated my header text to be the aforementioned font, but it only shows up as the fallback font, cursive Comic Sans.

Comment: did you try using `url()` instead of `local()`?

Comment: @Hybrid Yes, I tried url() before I tried local()

Comment: Did you make sure to invoke it? e.g. `h1 { font-family: "Francaise" }`?

Comment: @hybrid sorry for the long wait, but the answer is yes. I evoked it in my main header text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `@font-face` url without adding white space. Just rename your font and try the following structure.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Francaise';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('francaise-regular-demo.ttf'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Francaise Regular Demo'), local('Francaise Regular Demo'),
       url('francaise-regular-demo.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Use the `font-family: 'Francaise';` in your css.

Comment: This looked to be the right fix to my problem, but it is still not working. Perhaps their is an error in Firefox (the browser I am using)

Comment: I started out with the fonts in their own folder, but then I thought the issue might be my directory reference, so I put the fonts in the same folder as the CSS. I have tried removing spaces, changing the name, format, url to local, and different browsers. None of that has worked thus far.

Comment: can share the url?

Comment: If i've installed the fonts can I use them without all this complicated code to work in a font?

Comment: No its a simple method. share the live url.  I can assist you.

Comment: I could make a CodePen. The site is not public

Comment: Ok. share the url

Comment: https://codepen.io/Code-Cafe/pen/aMrwex that is the link to my newly made codepen

Comment: If you'd like I could send you what the directory looks like and font file names, etc.

Comment: Yes, I did sir or madam.

Comment: Call me saravana. you can try webfont generator. https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: Upload your `francaise` font and download your kit.

Comment: I did, i have them copied into the file, used the stylesheet format and reference and it still will not work...

Comment: Saravana, I managed to produce a positive result. I moved my code into a internal CSS and it has loaded my font. I don't wish to keep it this way, but at least I know it works. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=48242495548929278614 download the fonts from here . I uploaded with all type of fonts including stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

first check the

> Browser Support for Font Formats

use src for font

```
@font-face {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
   src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}

* {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

you can refer the site
http://fontsforweb.com/index.php

Comment: As I mentioned to @hybrid before, i used the url before using the local tag. I will try this, but doubtful that it will make a difference.